# What will be the Java Script Function To implement sliding animation on a <div> on MouseOver Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have following images

```
<div>
     <img src="leftarrow.png"/></br>
     <img src="insert.png"/></br>
    <img src="edit.png"/></br> 
    <img src="delete.png"/></br>
 </div>
```

Now what i want is that if a user brings mouse pointer over the image named "leftarrow" a vertical bar should slide in (which should be invisible previously) containing rest of the images i.e "insert", "edit" and "delete" like we have toolbox in Visual Studio etc
thanks in advance :)

Comment: why would u revert back to javascript , jquery is so evolved

Comment: @user1537158: Why do you think jQuery was no javascript?

Comment: @Ali: Why don't you have those three sliding images wrapped in an extra element?

Comment: actually i am a beginner in all this stuff
dont have any good idea how to do this all :(

Comment: why are [tag:codeigniter] and [tag:php] tagged?

Comment: @Bergi Sir if you proposed a solution of wrapping images in an extra element to me it will be highly appreciated :)

Comment: @Bhuvan Rikka because i am working on CodeIgniter thats why i thought to tagged them also
is there any problem in tagging them :P

Comment: @Bergi jquery already has what ali has asked for , javascript we might have to write codes

Comment: @Ali Your question doesn't deal with php or CI. So,if you tag them,it will attract php devs and when they see _nothing related to php_ or _a bad question_,it'd lead to downvotes(depends on the user). So i won't recommend it.So i removed the tags. If you want them,you can tag them again

Comment: @Bhuvan Rikka oh i got it now
thanks for telling dude :)

Comment: oh Com'on StackOverFlow Developers if you have no solution then please dont surprise me with a downvote :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I used in my webiste I had to do for IPT: [JQuery Effects from W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_effects.asp). This site has "try it yourself" where you can fiddle with the code and get to know and understand the workings of this jquery effect better. In order for it to work, you will need to either download or link to the jquery file (http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery.js)

you can use the `slideXX()` (where XX = direction) and use the 'speed' parameter to animate it. to your liking.

---

**UPDATE:** If you want to make something grow/shrink, you can use the same jquery file, but a different command (specifically either the `animate` or the `toggle` commands)

the syntax is: `$(selector).animate({params},duration,easing,callback);`
for the hide/show commands, the syntax is `$(selector).toggle(speed_in_milliseconds);`
EDIT: oh, and I almost forgot: use the `hide` command to hide the buttons on page load

Further information for this can also be found at [jquery effects - w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_effects.asp).

Hope it helps! If not, just comment and I will see what else can be done

Comment: thanks for your response
actually i am thinking to first disabled the images like edit, insert and delete and they will only reappear if a users bring mouse over the image named leftarrow
can you help me regarding this stuff???
thanks

Comment: You have me slightly confused. you want to show the edit, insert and delete buttons when the mouse hovers over the leftarrow? is that correct?

Comment: I've added further information. just program it to affect the buttons instead, and if you want the hide/show/animation to be instantaneous, just omit the `speed` arg